# How to set the color for shape in cgmutablepath?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicolor, cgpath

I am using cgmutablepath to draw a polygon where i would like to fill color for the polygon but it is not working and i have no idea why...

Below is my code:

```
var path = CGMutablePath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 127.5, y: 12.5))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 165.0, y: 13.0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 165.0, y: 50.5))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 127.5, y: 50.5))
        path.closeSubpath()

       var shape = CAShapeLayer()
       shape.path = path
       shape.lineWidth = 3.0
       shape.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
       shape.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
```

Comment: i have edit my question code and it is not working which the the shape with blue color is not showing

Comment: Are you adding the layer as a sublayer somewhere? Not related, but  don't you get warnings about *Variable ... was never mutated*?

Comment: we got the warnings about the var path was never mutated and we are not adding the layer as a sublayer somewhere...

Comment: So if you don't use the layer in a view environment it cannot work. A stand-alone layer will never be displayed. Regarding the warnings: Why don't you fix them by considering the suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing your code with this updated code :

```
    var path = CGMutablePath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 127.5, y: 12.5))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 165.0, y: 13.0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 165.0, y: 50.5))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 127.5, y: 50.5))
    path.closeSubpath()

   var shape = CAShapeLayer()
   shape.path = path
   shape.lineWidth = 3.0
   shape.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
   shape.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
   self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

Please try it out and comment in case of any error. Happy Coding.